# Joining tables when row matches multiple rows in other table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to join 3 tables (as presented below), but I can't figure out how to do it:

Table 1

```
vendor_id
---------
1
2
3
4
```

Table 2

```
cuisine_type | vendor_id
------------------------
a            |1
b            |1
c            |1
```

Table 3

```
cuisine_type|cuisine
--------------------
a           |pizza
b           |rice
c           |steak
```

I would like to join the 3 tables and get this:

```
vendor_id|cuisine_type|cuisine
------------------------------
1        |a, b, c     |pizza, steak, rice
2.......
```

I hope this makes sense. I'm very new to postgreSQL so maybe I'm missing something very easy/obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple join and an aggregation based on the vendor_id:

```
select v.vendor_id, 
       string_agg(ct.cuisine_type, ', ') as cuisine_type,
       string_agg(c.cuisine, ', ') as cuisine
from table_1 as v
   join table_2 as ct on v.vendor_id = ct.vendor_id
   join table_3 as c on ct.cuisine_type = c.cuisine_type
group by v.vendor_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your table structure looks a bit strange.  For instance, why does each cuisine type have only a single cuisine?  Normally, I would expect the vendor to be connected to the cuisines, and then each cuisine to have a type.

However, that is not *this* question.  With the data you have provided, you can use `string_agg()`:

```
select v.vendor_id, string_agg(cuisine_type, ', ') as cuisine_types,
       string_agg(cuisine, ', ') as cuisines
from table1 v left join
     table2 v2c
     on v.vendor_id = v2c.vendor_id left join
     table3 c
     on c.cuisine_type = v2c.cuisine_type
group by v.vendor_id;
```